# UWP Javascript - crop an image

Tags: javascript, uwp

I'm writing an app in UWP javascript for cropping the sides off images, cropping off the left-most and right-most pixels that are transparent in a png.

I have a function which I've written which is correctly reading the bytes and finding the left-bound and right-bound of the image -- eg if the first non-transparent pixel is 100 pixels in, and the last non-transparent is 200 pixels in, it's returning an object that looks like `{leftBound: 100, rightBound: 200, height: 50, width: 300}`.

So my issue is in saving a new image with those bounds. The only example code I could find was [this code in c#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7/sourcecode?fileId=70609&pathId=811380856). So I tried to follow it, like so:

```
async function processImage(stream) {
    const calcBounds = await getPixelBounds(stream.cloneStream());

    const transform = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform();
    transform.bounds.x = calcBounds.leftBound;
    transform.bounds.width = calcBounds.rightBound - calcBounds.leftBound;

    transform.bounds.height = calcBounds.height;

    transform.scaledHeight = transform.bounds.height;
    transform.scaledWidth = transform.bounds.width;

    const decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.createAsync(stream);

    const pixelFormat = decoder.bitmapPixelFormat;
    const alphaMode = decoder.bitmapAlphaMode;
    const dpiX = decoder.dpiX;
    const dpiY = decoder.dpiY;

    const data = await decoder.getPixelDataAsync(
        pixelFormat,
        alphaMode,
        transform,
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ExifOrientationMode.respectExifOrientation,
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ColorManagementMode.colorManageToSRgb
        );
    const pixels = data.detachPixelData();
    const outputFilename = "cropped.png";
    const encoderId = Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId;

    const folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
    const outputFile =
        await folder.createFileAsync(outputFilename,
            Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists);

    const outputStream = await outputFile.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
    outputStream.size = 0;
    const encoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(encoderId, outputStream);
    encoder.setPixelData(
        pixelFormat,
        alphaMode,
        calcBounds.rightBound - calcBounds.leftBound,
        calcBounds.height,
        dpiX,
        dpiY,
        pixels
    );

    await encoder.flushAsync();
    stream && stream.close();
    outputStream && outputStream.close();
}
```

The first thing I noticed when debugging was that the properties of `transform.bounds` weren't changing. In fact I'm pretty sure that's my primary issue, and the entire code might be fixed if I figure out how to set `transform.bounds`.

I tried just making a new object, `transform.bounds = {x:0, y:0, width: 0, height: 0}`, and then resetting the width and height as I do in the code later, but that didn't work.

In the c# sample, it uses `new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapBounds()`, but that doesn't exist in javascript...

[edit]
I tried this:

```
    const transform = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform();
    const bounds = { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 };
    bounds.x = calcBounds.leftBound;
    bounds.width = calcBounds.rightBound - calcBounds.leftBound;

    bounds.height = calcBounds.height;
    transform.bounds = bounds;
```

But it's causing an exception on the line where I do `const data = await decoder.getPixelDataAsync(...` saying that the parameter is incorrect

Comment: I found that I could just manually create the pixel array myself. I'd still rather use `transform.bounds`, seems more sensible...

Comment: Not so sure the details about the "parameter is incorrect". For your original code, what's the result if you manually set the bounds? For your edit code, what about try convert it by using this code when you are trying to set it back to your image control: SoftwareBitmap.Convert(inputBitmap,BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

Comment: When I try to manually set the bounds via `transform.bounds.x = 2`, for example, or any other property, they stay 0. When I manually set them like `transform.bounds = {x:2, y:2, ...}` I get the 'parameter is incorrect' error

Comment: Do you mind to share a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the demo image that you are using?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I've made a github repo here: https://github.com/samjross/CroppingTool

Comment: Cannot get your sample works. Anyway, from my side, I may give this a try. Create a decoder and assign a new softwarebitmap using decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync. After doing this I may have to create a new file based on this softwarebitmap. As the src of img only accept url, the file has to be created from app data folder. This does not sound like a reasonable workaround. Do you just want to crop to show a image or do you actually want to crop the source? It seems using web related ways are more recommend here.

Comment: I wanted to save a new image that is a cropped version of the source. No need to show anything.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I'm not sure why you cannot get it to work though. Made in Visual Studio 2017 as a uwp javascript app, with no special stuff added.

Comment: I've made a discussion with my colleage and we consider that you may need to focus on web part instead of UWP part. UWP seems do not provide a good way for you to do this crop action and src only accept url. So it's hard for the desktop method to work here.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT it's strange that the api exists for C# but not for javascript, despite every other aspect of the Imaging api seemingly being there.

Comment: Yep and I would recommend you to provide your feedback to [uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform). I cannot guess a reason for this kind of issue. Raise your feedback is more reasonable in my mind.